# CSS Header Being Pushed Beyond Content

Tags: html, css

So I recently added a jQuery powered sliding panel to my page that I finally got working... the problem is that when it slides out, it pushes my header further than the actual page content... it's very evident if you visit my site and click the "MENU" button in the sidebar along the left side of the content area... the panel will slide out, and the header moves out of position.

www.brooksrealtysvc.com/privacy

I'm sure the issue lies somewhere in the CSS used for the header... Could anyone help me identify what I can change to help correct this issue?

**Relevant CSS**

```
#banner-wrap
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 50;
}

#banner-bar
{
  height: 177px;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

#banner-hood
{
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 60;
}

#banner-logo
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -180px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: 80;
}

#banner-text
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -33px;
  margin-left: -346px;
  z-index: 80;
}

#banner-svc
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 550px;
  z-index: 80;
}
```

**Relevant HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="banner-wrap">
    <div id="banner-bar">
        <div id="banner-hood">
            <center><img src="http://test.vtisvc.com/wp-content/themes/brk_2013/images/header_hood.png" style="float:center"></center>
            <div id="banner-logo"><center><img src="http://test.vtisvc.com/wp-content/themes/brk_2013/images/header_logo4.png" style="float:center"></center></div>
            <div id="banner-svc"><center><img src="http://test.vtisvc.com/wp-content/themes/brk_2013/images/header_svc.png"></center></div>
            <div id="banner-text"><center><a href="http://www.brooksrealtysvc.com"><font face="georgia" color="#8a0304&quot;">HOME</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.brooksrealty.idxco.com/idx/8087/featured.php"><font face="georgia" color="#8a0304">LISTINGS</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.brooksrealty.idxco.com/idx/8087/roster.php"><font face="georgia" color="#8a0304">AGENTS</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.brooksrealty.idxco.com/idx/8087/basicSearch.php"><font face="georgia" color="#8a0304">SEARCH MLS</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.brooksrealtysvc.com/rentals"><font face="georgia" color="#8a0304">RENTALS</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.brooksrealtysvc.com/history"><font face="georgia" color="#8a0304">HISTORY</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.brooksrealtysvc.com/contact"><font face="georgia" color="#8a0304">CONTACT</font></a></center></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `<center>`...

Comment: I'll readily admit I am NOT a CSS pro, I'm barely an amateur... but the <center> tags in the HTML there let me get the effect I wanted (as described below in my reply to JoshC) which is a header that is fixed and allows for a long page to scroll "behind" it while it remains fixed at top... I'm sure there's a more elegant way to make it work, but that's how I managed to get it done. Just looking for how to make the header and content sheet stay together, whether they slide or not, when that panel pops out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following in the `head` section of your website:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.open').click(function(){
        $('#banner-hood').toggleClass('displace');
    });
});
</script>
```

You will also need to add the following line in your CSS:

```
.displace { margin-left:120px; }
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/ZUrT7/)

For the transition add the following to your CSS:

```
#banner-hood {
    -webkit-transition:all .35s;
    -moz-transition:all .35s;
    transition:all .35s;
}
```

Comment: That works, yes... but it also removes the scroll effect for the header - if you'll notice (click Privacy Statement in the bottom right corner to load a page long enough for the effect to be seen) the content area of the page is intended to scroll "behind" a fixed header at the top... so any idea how I can incorporate both the panel AND keep the "fixed" header at the top?

Comment: @proxlars Didn't realize it is fixed for that purpose. I though you were using it for positioning reasons. As for having both, there is no solution in pure CSS, you would have to use JS, as a fixed element is relative to the viewport and not surrounding elements - are you fine with that? Given you are already using it.

Comment: I'd be fine with anything that helped me keep the header as a fixed element to preserve the scroll effect, and let me simultaneously use the panel to good effect... but my javascript knowledge is limited and I doubt I could come up with something on my own... Any idea were I could acquire some knowledge/help on the issue?

Comment: Thanks! That did, indeed, fix it... you're a miracle worker in my book! There is a bit of lag in how the header moves in comparison to everything else, but that's not too big of an issue... I'll take it! You've been a tremendous help, thank you again.

Comment: Thanks again, Josh, for all your help!